# XSL v1 Reg-expression - find patterns in text - IBM Watson explorer WEX

Tags: xml, xslt, watson

Best

I'm trying to construct an XSL script which can retrieve the following strings back, [ in a text (if it occurs in that text) ]:

The pattern which I basically need is **3.2.14P5879** or **14.1.1Z5526**

Thus:  **Digits Dot Digits Dot Digit Letter-P_or_Z  Digits**

for example, if I've the text:

There was an issue with project **3.2.14P5879**, regarding to document **14.1.1Z5526**-ABC.docx it says that we've to use the documents of *"**14.1.1P5526** - xyz.pdf"*

Then it would be amazing if I could have the next result:

```
 - <content name="test">3.2.14P5879</content> 
 - <content name="test">14.1.1Z5526</content>
 - <content name="test">14.1.1P5526</content>
```

---

What I've done so far, and doesn't work is, checking if some positions matches a vocabulary. (the code works) But the result is wrong. It will only check the statement at the beginning of a text.

```
<xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select="concat($vUpper, $vLower)" />
<xsl:variable name="vDigits" select="'0123456789'" />
<xsl:variable name="vDot" select="'.'" />
<xsl:variable name="vProject" select="'PZ'" />


<xsl:template match="/">

  <document>
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[text()]">


      <content name="Lengte" length="{string-length(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </content>


      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when
          test="string-length(translate(substring(., 1, 2), $vDigits, '')) = 0     and string-length(translate(substring(., 3, 1), $vDot, '')) = 0 and string-length(translate(substring(., 5, 1), $vDot, '')) = 0 and string-length(translate(substring(., 6, 2), $vDigits, '')) = 0 and string-length(translate(substring(., 8, 1), $vProject, '')) = 0  and string-length(translate(substring(., 9, 4), $vDigits, '')) = 0"
        >

          <content name="A" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 11)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 2)" />
          </content>

          <content name="B" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 11)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 4, 1)" />
          </content>

          <content name="C" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 11)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 6, 2)" />
          </content>

          <content name="D" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 11)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 9, 4)" />
          </content>

          <content name="E" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 11)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 7)" />
          </content>

          <content name="F" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </content>



        </xsl:when>


        <xsl:when
          test="string-length(translate(substring(., 1, 1), $vDigits, '')) = 0     and string-length(translate(substring(., 2, 1), $vDot, '')) = 0 and string-length(translate(substring(., 4, 1), $vDot, '')) = 0 and string-length(translate(substring(., 5, 2), $vDigits, '')) = 0 and string-length(translate(substring(., 7, 1), $vProject, '')) = 0  and string-length(translate(substring(., 8, 4), $vDigits, '')) = 0"
        >

          <content name="A" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 1)" />
          </content>

          <content name="B" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 3, 1)" />
          </content>

          <content name="C" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 5, 2)" />
          </content>

          <content name="D" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, 4)" />
          </content>

          <content name="E" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 7)" />
          </content>

          <content name="F" Proj-name="{.}" Proj="{substring(., 1, 10)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </content>

        </xsl:when>



      </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </document>

</xsl:template>
```

Why do I need this? and WHY XSL Version 1.0 ???
At this moment, I'm working with Watson Explorer 11.0.2 and I've to retrieve custom Meta-Data, which I can access via the html-xsl Action (custom-converter)(Regex - regex-text perl-regex perl-regex-text are also available, but I don't have a single clue how to even use them (THANK YOU IBM for your PERFECT documentation))

Thus to keep it short, Unless someone who can help me to retrieve the "codes" via Regex in *watson explorer - custom converter - action* (I know the reg-expression) -

I have to have some help to retrieve the codes back from a text via XSL version 1.0

(PS, Watson explorer is an enterprise search, web scraper/crawler)

Comment: AFAIK, Watson Explorer supports a variety of extension functions, incl. regex. I believe the `viv:match()` function is the one you want, but I am not a Watson user, so I cannot test this. To do this in pure XSLT 1.0, without regex support, would be *very* difficult. Do you at least know how many digits can there be in each group of digits?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - The length is variable because some numbers stand for the year and other for the project ID. thus it can differ.
The main problem with regex is, we have no clue how to start --> e.g. when using the html-xsl I knew that after **<xsl:template match="/">**, i can define some elements. But with Regex, There is no single piece of decent documentation for that action function. Also No example. (i would rather love to use regex but ... you've to know how you can use it, i guess)

Comment: I suspect it behaves the same as http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the [EXSLT regex extension functions](http://exslt.org/regexp/index.html) (as implemented in `libxslt`). I suspect that the regex extension functions that are part of Watson Explorer have the same behavior.

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>There was an issue with project 1.2.34P5678, regarding to document 23.4.5Z6789-ABC.docx it says that we've to use the documents of "35.66.78P999 - xyz.pdf"</item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
extension-element-prefixes="regexp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:call-template name="extract-matches">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="extract-matches">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="regex" select="'\d+\.\d+\.\d+[PZ]\d+'"/>
    <xsl:if test="regexp:test($text, $regex)">
        <xsl:variable name="matching-substring" select="regexp:match($text, $regex)" />
        <match>
            <xsl:value-of select="$matching-substring" />
        </match>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="extract-matches">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $matching-substring)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <match>1.2.34P5678</match>
  <match>23.4.5Z6789</match>
  <match>35.66.78P999</match>
</output>
```

Comment: don't know it yet, if it works,  i tried it very fast,  but i think that the call with  regexp wasn't correct,  i've to look it up :)  but i trust your advice XD

Comment: Do note that you need to use Watson's extension functions instead, in the `viv` namespace. On that the documentation is quite clear.

Comment: Hey, with renaming it to viv,  it looks like it works. But there is an issue with regex : It uses regex 0.12 (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8NLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.engine.man.doc/r_viv_match.html &  regex specification)  -  Do you've any experiences with that? :)

Comment: I am afraid that's way out of my area of expertise. Is it possible you need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]`?

Comment: at this moment, I'm not on site. (probably next Wednesday)  But I'll give you an answer / feedback as soon as it works :) 
+ thanks for your input :)

Comment: I've a question. What if I only want unique values? Is it possible to create a list, where I store all the values in, (a set/hashlist?)
and use them then afterwards?

Comment: You have several options: you could collect the matches into a variable, then use either Muenchian grouping or the `set:distinct()` extension function on the variable (after converting it to a node-set). Or modify the recursive template to store the values and test each new value against the stored list before adding it.